# Where do I place commas in a compound-complex sentence?

Tags: commas

I don't know if I should use a comma before "and" in this sentence.

> I grunted from the weight of the dresser and after a pause, the doorbell rang again. I gave up with a huff and went outside.

I think "I grunted from the weight of the dresser" is an independent clause and "after a pause" is a dependent clause. Thus, there should be no comma before "and". "After a pause" also connects to the independent clause "the doorbell rang again", so there should be a comma between the two.

Am I correct in my assumption?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comma placement for a parenthetical after "and"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/422011/comma-placement-for-a-parenthetical-after-and)

Comment: The second independent clause — *after a pause, the doorbell rang again* — contains a dependent clause — *after a pause*. _I grunted from the weight of the dresser, and after a pause, the doorbell rang again._ You can also look at it this way: _I grunted from the weight of the dresser, and the doorbell rang again after a pause._

Comment: @TinfoilHat I would say that the comma should come _after_ the and since "after a pause" is parenthetical but "and" is integral to the sentence. The sentence without parenthesis reads "I grunted from the weight of the dresser and the doorbell rang again."